# Would this PHP function provide sufficient data hashing?

Tags: php, hash, base64

I got a function I wrote up around 2 years back. The function uses base64 encode method along with sha1 hash and bunch of pre-defined values. Here is the function

```
     function secure_encode($x) { 
         return strtr(base64_encode(substr($_SESSION['Cksum'],rand(0,28),4) . $x), '+/=', '-_+');
     }

     $express = array();

     $express['0'] = "58464db46ba2ea0f54.8030317175114db46ba2ea1004.65676456123564db46ba2ea10b2.4389053856-5caecd9b6220eaea81e40641caad165ad681d49c-Bh8j1kU.kAIznsh5WhHH-XO5FJFGU6cMySblUAKkpdg==/".date();

     $express['1'] = "113354db46791181958.25326465113804db46791181a07.35447338301094db46791181ab9.28188138-c5438adfef452a06fffd8a1e755322796122620d-O1dnRG.KafUv8.JcISrn-Nhab7EDL.2lkQ68WfT1Pzg==/";

     $express['2'] = "299084db46ac385b7d9.3958582716614db46ac385ba68.3911624024184db46ac385bee5.3681503764-b249050b2cc8ec9a9a24e6775fd6d679982ce35e-E7rS6jrbjYdHptZPAe4v-WNwjOR1HEEMJURn/RUN.AA==/";

     $express['3'] = "233534db46ae7c7a2d7.98941083259824db46ae7c7a390.88346488191674db46ae7c7a449.03466538-08741422c3f59599e4c170ed4871e387a921268f-L/pA2jYJ/mEjZmyjHWt5-fVSwQyCRfxsR8lCmQkw2aw==/";

     $express['4'] = "107034db46b02569962.3398546439324db46b02569a26.08097334169974db46b02569ad1.521504520-e141a88ba3299debc3abc9a04d5953a7604df28e-JGkKsXa19ZEPuasSZLC5-B8oD3S68DPUL3zrZTjELZg==/";

     $pass = $_POST['auth_pass'];
     $hash = secure_encode((sha1($express['0']."//!%$!*&^@n3.".$pass).sha1($express['2']."//!%$!*&^@n3.".$pass)));
```

For example hashing value: **123abc** would return

> NjY1NGI0ZTIzMTc5NmViNGU5MjhiMDgyZmUyMDYwNDAzYWQzM2NjYTJmZTYzYjk2ZTg3MzVkMTRmMTc2MjI0NjdkMjY2ZDg0MjAyMGY1ZTc+

Based on the code snippet would this hashing be sufficient to hash basic user data like First/Last Names, Telephone #, Address and D.O.B or would it be better to use some other form of hash? Also if the snippet can be improved on please point out at sections that can make it better.

**Edit:** I currently use this function to hash user passwords on a forum software I made. And I never had any issues with user accounts being breached or passwords stolen.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Hashing or *encrypting* the data?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I guess trying to protect it from spying eyes

Comment: *I never got hacked* `!=` *secure practices*. It doesn't even prove luck. Use `crypt()` with `BLOWFISH`. Do not, repeat, do no "roll your own" hashing or algorithm methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is called security through obscurity. Just because someone doesn't know your algorithm doesn't make it secure. If someone were to break into your website and look at your hashing function, your "custom" hashes would be easy to attack, since all you're doing is base64-encoding a salted SHA1 hash.

Don't write your own functions. Use trusted hashing functions like [Bcrypt](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords), which are expensive to attack.

Also, be sure to read [this article](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that if the Salt Keys (Express in my case) where to be exposed the entire system would fall.

Comment: Yes I know thats not very good and is a very poor security if this values where to be exposed. Well thank you I am looking into Bcrypt

Comment: @user2108921 - Salts are not required to be secret, they're meant to be suitably random enough that the mathematical complexity of attacking that many individual secondary unique masks on the hashed data would prove so time consuming, it would not be feasible or profitable to bother. On another note, rolling your own approach to hashing or encrypting, it's *easier* by orders of magnitude to do something that dramatically *weakens* whatever you've designed that does work, than it is to somehow on your own design a truly legitimate method. Read Bruce Schneier.